# What is important questions when evaluating and purchasing Software Systems?

Tags: software-development

Im currently working with analyzing and evaluating systems like customer portals, sales systems, CRM etc. Now i got the task to put together a common template we can use when evaluating these. I have searched through some research but they are really dry and not giving me any good input. Therefor i would like to ask people with experience:

What is the most important questions when evaluating systems?

Is there any known practices or templates i should use or avoid?

Is there any "new" or modern ways of analyzing and evaluating software?

Would be awesome with some input.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Unfortunately your question does not fit our purpose well at the moment. Please do read [this meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/17502/edit) your question. You will need to rescope it. This site requires questions to state the goal the asker wants to fulfill and looks for the right tool for the job. This is not a discussion forum. TBH, I don't think this question can be made to fit into our scope.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Would it make sense to migrate the question to Meta SR and tag it as `discussion`?

Comment: @Timmy No. This question belongs on a discussion forum. Neither Meta nor any other element of the SE Network is a good fit for that. While it is an interesting question, I can't see how it could be made into a good Q&A fit. (I'm all eyes if someone has an idea how that could be done)

Comment: @Timmy Also, Meta is about the site SR.SE - Its not there to discuss software recommendations but to discuss the workings and rules of this very site.

Comment: With a lot of work and thought this could be made to fit programmers.SE, but the rules there need to be followed of course (and I am not sufficiently active there to propose migration).

Comment: So, where could i post this then?

Comment: Try [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) like @AngeloFuchs suggested, but make sure to read [their guidelines](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first and rephrase your question accordingly

Comment: I knew I had this discussion already! @Lebowski Have a look at [this meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/98/94) where we discuss the topicality of these kind of questions and where allquixotic posted some places where they can be posted.

Comment: Ill try blasting it over there. Thanks guys.. delete this one if you want :)

Comment: @Lebowski please note the "a lot of work and thought".  The reposted version of this question has not added any of that.  Please also consider reading [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/40980) - the question as written is seeking a discussion.